# Actualizar múltiples registros con el mismo valor?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Como puedo actualizar múltiples registros con el mismo valor a la vez?

es decir tengo la siguiente tabla, y dependiendo de la ruta y jornada cambiar en la columna **set_noved**, el 1 por el 0 en varios registros que cumplan la condición, al mismo tiempo

Mi BD

```
id |  usuario  | set_noved | placa | ruta | jornada |
-----------------------------------------------------
1  | Andres    | 1         | TTY651|  H   |  A      |
-----------------------------------------------------
2  | Maria     | 1         | TTY651|  L   |  B      |
-----------------------------------------------------
3  | Claudia   | 1         | TTY651|  L   |  A      |
-----------------------------------------------------
4  | Juan      | 1         | TTY651|  H   |  A      |
-----------------------------------------------------
5  | Maria     | 1         | TTY651|  H   |  A      |
-----------------------------------------------------
```

Mi php scritp

```
if ( $_SERVER[ "REQUEST_METHOD" ] == "POST" ) {
    require 'conn.php';
    resetNov();
}

function resetNov() {
    global $connect;

    $set = $_POST[ "set_nov" ];
    $placa = $_POST[ "placa" ];
    $ruta = $_POST[ "ruta" ];
    $jornada = $_POST[ "jornada" ];


    $query = "UPDATE escolar_tracker SET set_noved='$set' WHERE placa='$placa' ruta='$ruta' and jornada='$jornada'";

    mysqli_query( $connect, $query )or die( mysqli_error( $connect ) );
    mysqli_close( $connect );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si ejecutas esa consulta en una BD, te va a cambiar todos los registros que cumplan las condiciones.

```
UPDATE escolar_tracker SET set_noved='$set' WHERE placa='$placa' ruta='$ruta' and jornada='$jornada'
```

Si placa = TTY651, ruta = H y jornada = A, tu consulta modificaría los siguientes registros

```
UPDATE escolar_tracker SET set_noved='$set' WHERE placa='TTY651' ruta='H' and jornada='A' 

id |  usuario  | set_noved | placa | ruta | jornada |
-----------------------------------------------------
1  | Andres    | 1         | TTY651|  H   |  A      |
-----------------------------------------------------
4  | Juan      | 1         | TTY651|  H   |  A      |
-----------------------------------------------------
5  | Maria     | 1         | TTY651|  H   |  A      |
-----------------------------------------------------
```

Finalmente según sea el valor de set_noved='$set', cambiará el valor de dicha columna, para que tuvieras un cambio $set tendría que valer 0.